# I get rid of class in CSS and my paragraph element wont work...WHY?

Tags: html, css, django, class

Im using Django web framework for my first project, trying to adjust my fonts. However, after various trial and error I was able to get a new font to render on my page. The problem is that when I get ride of my .font class, the p { } element no longer works for whatever reason and the font remains unchanged. I can't get my font to change any other way... I have NO idea why this is happening, driving me crazy...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/custom2.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<!-- header table, no text displayed -->
<Br>
<Br>
<table  align='center' width='75%'  border= '0px'>
 <tr>
  <td bgcolor='transparent'>
  </td>
 </tr>
 s
</table>


<!-- main body -->

<body background = "{% static 'personal/img/background.jpg' %}">
<table align='center' width='75%' border='1px'>
<tr>
 <td bgcolor='white'>



    <div class="body" style="min-height:95%; ">
    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <br>
                  <center>
                    <img src="{% static 'personal/img/profile.jpg' %}" class="responsive-img" style='max-height:100px;' alt="face">
                  </center>
              </div>

     <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <br>
      <p>test paragraph</p>
              </div>
        </div>


<!-- navigation bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href='/header/'>HQ</a></li>
     <!--<li><a href='/blog/'>Blog</a></li>-->
     <li><a href='/bucket/'>TO DO</a></li>
     <li><a href='/influencers/'>TO MEET</a></li>
     <li><a href='/contact/'>TO CONTACT</a></li>
     <li><a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/pete-humiston-30255a5b' target='_blank'>LinkedIn</a></li>
             </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


               {% block content %}
               {% endblock %}   


    <footer>
  <!-- This is a footer I'll leave for later. Overkill.
        <div class="container-fluid" style='margin-left:15px'>
            <p><a href="#" target="blank">Contact</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">LinkedIn</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">Twitter</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">Google+</a></p>
   --> 
        </div>
    </footer>   


 </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Custom2.css

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita');
</style>


.font {
 font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
 }

p {
 font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

An external css file (`Custom2.css`) does not need `<style>` tags - just put straight CSS in it. The presence of those tags will break the next CSS rule. So if you have those tags in your CSS file, and you remove `.font`, then `p` won't be read since it will now come after those tags.

The contents should be...

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita');
.font {
  font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: @Phum you just deleted your "Navigation Bar Left/Center Align? CSS & HTML" post. Why? And why haven't you accepted an answer on any of the questions you've asked?